# Python string replace randomly

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm interested in python, its simplicity and readability and flexibility.
And I want to replace string randomly. What I mean is

```
animals = ["cat", "dog", "monkey", "tiger"]

template = "$animal fights with $animal. $animal can play with $animal. Sth $animal sth $animal ..."
```

I want replace `$animal` with randomly chosen element in `animals` every occurrence.
For example, I want to output `"dog fights with cat. cat can play with tiger. Sth monkey sth dog ..."` like this.
Of course, it can be solved with boring code. But is there any "**Pythonic**" single-line code?

Comment: did you consider using random to randomise the elements of the list??

Comment: I mean, template is in the external resource file, And I want random sentence from resource template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd prefer something like this for simple cases:

```
import random

animals = ["cat", "dog", "monkey", "tiger"]


def ra():
    return random.choice(animals)


print(f'{ra()} fights with {ra()}. {ra()} can play with {ra()}. Sth {ra()} sth {ra()} ...')
```

But this is closer to your starting point, you may prefer it:

```
import re
import random

animals = ["cat", "dog", "monkey", "tiger"]
template = "$animal fights with $animal. $animal can play with $animal. Sth $animal sth $animal ..."

print(re.sub(r'\$animal', lambda _: random.choice(animals), template))
```

Note that both solutions don't care how many animals you're replacing.

Comment: The solution with f-strings is only applicable to python 3, despite being the best solution I’ve seen. According to the tag, the OP uses python 2.

Comment: Thank you, for your suggestion. It solved my problem. If it works on python 2, I want to give you double marks.@Grismar

Comment: Underscore is not necessary after `lambda` i there's no arguments.

Comment: @OlvinRoght that's incorrect. `re.sub` will feed the match to the function and the lambda will fail if you don't provide a parameter to accept it. That's why it's an underscore, indicating the position is accepted, but the value discarded. But if you know of a way to change `re.sub` behaviour to avoid that, that would improve the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `random.shuffle()` and `.format()` like this

```
template = '{} fights with {}. {} can play with {}. Sth {} sth {}'.format(random.choice(animals), random.choice(animals), random.choice(animals), random.choice(animals), random.choice(animals), random.choice(animals))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

animals = ["cat", "dog", "monkey", "tiger"]

template = "random.choice(animals) fights with random.choice(animal). random.choice(animal) can play with random.choice(animal). Sth random.choice(animal) sth random.choice(animal) ..."
```

Comment: I guess you mean `f"{random.choice(animals)} fights..."` ?

Comment: F-string is for Python 3 not Python 2

Comment: Basically `random.choice(name_of_list)` will return a random element of the lis

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But, template can be placed in external resource file. And writing code in a resource file is not a appropriate way, I think. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.split()`:

```
from random import choice

res = "".join(s + choice(animals) for s in template.split("$animal")[:-1]) + template.rsplit("$animal", 1)[1]
```